# Can i change the one viewPager adapter to other viewPager adapter on button click?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I want to change the viewPager adapter on button click like

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
button1.setOnClickListener(){
adapter1 = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);  // adapter 1
pager.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
button2.setOnClickListener(){
adapter2 = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);  // adapter 2
pager.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Is it possible to do..?

Comment: Yes it Seems! didn't you tried it?

Comment: After few example i got to know how to do this... It is simple....